# Audio Transmission using LED

Tags: audio

Referring to the attached schematic. The optical system setup is to transfer audio using LED. At the receiver end I failed to sense any audio signal. I have checked both LEDs using oscilloscope and the signal seems to give pk-pk 340mV.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsYt5g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

hi this is the oscilloscope output. the upper signal is transmitter LED and lower one is Received LED signal.

[image]

Also the following image showing yellow RCA (receiver LED wires connected as RCA wire) going in the LED TV.

[image]

---

I am using the below schematic to gain back the voltage level from the receiver led generated signal. Instead of variable resistor I am using 10K resistor with the input. It worked. Special thanks to Wouter for his help ). The audio quality is degraded. The sound is very low. Any suggestions on how to improve?

[image]

Comment: Use CTRL+M to use stackexchange intergrated schematic draw.

Comment: hi some of the features difficult to represent. hence drawing manually. apologies for any inconvenience. thanks

Comment: What's a CVBS?  It seems strange that the same thing can be used to drive a LED as receive the signal from a photodiode.  Also, what part are you asking about, how to drive the LED to make audio-modulated light, or how detect this modulated light back into a audio signal?  The whole system is rather broad.  Ask what specifically you are stuck on.

Comment: As I said in my question, I failed to retrieve any audio output even-though my oscilloscope reading suggest that the signal received is identical to signal transmitted.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I suspect CVBS stands for some sort of [Color,Video,Blanking and Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video) converter/interface.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this mightr work in some circustances, but where did you get the idea that this exact circuit should work for your situation?

At the sending side you have a LED, a 3V battery, and an audio output in series. Most audio outputs are AC couped, so there won't be any DC component for the LED, and the AC component will be too weak for the LED to light up. Which is probably all the better, because 3V DC would kill the LED.

What might work is battery, LED, and some series resistor (100 Ohm, 1k), and then somehow couple the AC onto the circuit (I would put a capacitor in series, take for instance 470 uF).

Comment: hi wouter thanks for your comment. could you please draw a schematic so that i can follow the instruction and try it out. Also i dont understand when you say this circuit may not be used at all situation?

Comment: Also i am supplying 4.69 vdc to the led for last 8 hours or so. the led is not killed yet. the problem is cant seem to sense audio at the receiver end.

Comment: Does the sending LED light up?

Comment: hi wouter, yes the LED lights up at the transmitter end. it transmits the audio signal. As I said, I probed the receiver LED and transmitter LED to see the signal distortion. Here I attach a picture for you to visualize. The Yellow is input (transmitter) and green is receiver LED. The problem is that I cant get any audio from the rca cable connected to my LED Display.

Comment: What is a CVBS, what audio level are you expecting? I think you should use two same-color primary LEDs.

Comment: hi my CVBS is actually a RCA Cable. it can be either left or right. please see the pics above. i have attached my current scenario.

Comment: What type of input are you using at the receiving end? I a microphone level input might work, a line level input very probably won't.

Comment: the receiving LED +/- is connected to the RCA cable main/ground. Then the RCA is directly connected to the TV AUDIO in as you can see in the pic above. Yellow is the cable color.

Comment: Also why wont it work with the direct TV input? Please help to elaborate.

Comment: Aasuming the two LEDs are close and well aimed at each other you might expect a signal level at the receiving LED that is waaaay lower than what you feed to the sending LED, as a rough esitmate a factor 100 or 1000. A longer distance or incorrect aim will increase the factor.

Comment: the proximity between the 2 leds are less than a centimeter. when you say signal level, do you mean voltage level of the signal? is there any way to amplify this signal on the receiver end?